# How does the BIP340 lift_x algorithm work?

Tags: python, cryptography, secp256k1, schnorr-signatures, x-only-pubkeys

Couple questions of code that I'm reviewing trying to learn schnorr sigs.

Why do we want an odd private key? I see even tests on the private key and then subtract it from the SECP256K1 Order to get an odd point?

Schnorr verify seems to need the square root of a point ,specifically this code here, why and what is this doing? I'm confused on what is happening conceptually.

```py
def lift_x(x: int) -> Optional[Point]:
    if x >= p:
        return None
    y_sq = (pow(x, 3, p) + 7) % p #<-the curve
    y = pow(y_sq, (p + 1) // 4, p) # why is this __floordiv__ 4?
    if pow(y, 2, p) != y_sq:
        return None
    return (x, y if y & 1 == 0 else p-y) # make y odd if there is a sqrt?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```py
def lift_x(x: int) -> Optional[Point]:
```

This is a function that given an X coordinate, computes one of the two corresponding Y coordinates on the curve; specifically, the even one.

Every possible value in the field of coordinates (integers modulo *p*, where *p = 2<sup>256</sup> - 2<sup>32</sup> - 977*) has exactly 0 points on the curve *y<sup>2</sup> = x<sup>3</sup> + 7*, or exactly two. In case there are two points with a given X coordinate, the corresponding Y coordinates will be each other's negation *(modulo p)*, and one will be even, and one will be odd. This *lift_x* function returns the one with the even Y.

```py
    y_sq = (pow(x, 3, p) + 7) % p #<-the curve
```

This computes *y_sq = y<sup>2</sup>*, using the fact that it equals *x<sup>3</sup> + 7* (*mod p*), using the curve equation.

```py
    y = pow(y_sq, (p + 1) // 4, p) # why is this __floordiv__ 4?
```

This computes the square root *y* of the value *y_sq* we determined in the previous now. In general, modular square roots can be computed using the [Tonelli-Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm), but for the secp256k1 modulus, this algorithm simply boils down to computing *y_sq<sup>(p+1)/4</sup> mod p*. In Python, we need to write this *(p+1)/4* as `(p+1)//4` because we want exact integer arithmetic. `(p+1)/4` would compute an approximate floating point number only.

```py
    if pow(y, 2, p) != y_sq:
        return None
```

This verifies whether the computed value *y* is actually the modular square root of *y_sq*. If the input *x* value was not a valid X coordinate on the curve, then *x<sup>3</sup> + 7* won't be a square, and thus won't have a square root. However, the formula *y_sq<sup>(p+1)/4</sup>* always yields a result, even when *y_sq* doesn't have a square root. So we need to check whether *y<sup>2</sup> = y_sq*. If not, we return `None` immediately: the input X has no corresponding Y coordinates.

```py
    return (x, y if y & 1 == 0 else p-y) # make y odd if there is a sqrt?
```

This simply negates *y* (modulo *p*) if *y* is odd, thereby finding the other (even) solution. This guarantees returning the even Y coordinate out of the two solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I see it now, it looks like it is for consistency. When we do ecc point add, the result will be significantly different for the point that has a 'negative' 7 than the point with a 'positive'? Or does it have something to do with key compression?

Comment: Given a fixed X coordinate, the two curve points with that coordinate are each other's negation (in ECC logic, `-(x,y) = (x,-y)`). So the choice very much matters: `point1 + lift_x_odd(x2) = point1 - lift_x(x2)` (so it'd be negation instead of addition), where `lift_x_odd` is a hypothetical variant of `lift_x` which maps to the odd Y coordinate rather than the even one. Note that it's not a negative/positive 7 (changing the sign of the 7 would be changing the curve equation, rendering it entirely insecure). All we're doing is choosing which of the solutions for Y to pick.

Comment: Thanks, that really clears things up for me and furthers my understanding.